# Query within a single table that displays unique rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

This is for Microsoft Access 2007.

I just have one table -

```
F1  F2  F3
1   A    B
1   A    B
2   C    B
```

I want my query to display unique rows only and also display count in the last column.

RESULT:

```
F1  F2  F3  F4
1   A    B   2
2   C    B   1
```

Comment: Didn't know where to start. Solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a query where you `GROUP BY` those 3 fields.  The fourth field expression will use the `Count()` function to give you the number of rows within each group.

```
SELECT
    F1,
    F2,
    F3,
    Count(*) AS F4
FROM YourTableNameHere
GROUP BY
    F1,
    F2,
    F3
```

This query should be easy to create from Design View of the Access query designer.  If it's not obvious at first, switch to SQL View, paste in the SQL, and replace `YourTableNameHere` with the name of your table.  Then you can switch back to Design View to see how the query is represented there.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed. i have no experience with SQL. thank you very much for the help!!!!

Comment: I think i get popup boxes asking for Value because some of the F1 has blank/null value. I dont want it to display these. Could you shedd some light? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I tried the Design View and i still get pop up saying Enter Parameter Value.

Comment: nm. it was a typo. the field name contained Space. I ommitted them by accident.  everything works flawlessly now. thank you so much, Hansup, and have a great weekend!!!!!

Comment: O wait. I lied. I encountered another problem - only F2 has to be unique and it displays all the fields for that row. The codes above returns everything.

Comment: Rats!  I tried to invite you to a chat session but you don't have enough points yet.  I don't understand your last comment but it sounds like you maybe want something different than the example in your question.  You can revise the question to show what you want now, or submit a new question with the current requirements.  The second option may get you an answer quicker because I have to leave soon.